# HTML Canvas Trigonometry

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, trigonometry

I'm not great with trig, but I've had to employ it heavily to achieve my desired results. Something about my math is off [broken link] (right-click).

Can someone take a look at movement.js? I'm trying to get the circle to move in the direction of the right-click.

(If anyone else sees this question, know that I've updated the page with a working example)

Comment: what should it be doing that it is not?

Comment: Nice circles. Now, what is it you're asking here?

Comment: Sorry guys, should have been more clear. I want the circle to move in the direction of the mouse click. That behavior is almost functioning, except it appears to be off by 90 degrees or something.

Comment: "HTML Canvas trigonometry" should be the same as normal trigonometry. Perhaps you should include the relevant code instead of making us search for it. Also, it looks like there's more wrong with it than just the direction being off by 90° (which would probably mean you just had your axes flipped). The movement occasionally reverses itself when you click in the same place repeatedly.

Comment: It's too much code to post. I guess I've been spoiled by Chrome inspect element. And I know more is wrong, which is why I said "trig help" instead of "rotation help". And I'm just trying to be as specific as possible with the title per Stack Overflow guidelines. Thanks for the unnecessary downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
scrollX = scrollX+(Math.cos(d_to_r(direction)))*step;
scrollY = scrollY+(Math.sin(d_to_r(direction)))*step;
```

with

```
var factor=direction>0&&direction<90 || direction>180&&direction<270?-1:1
scrollX = scrollX+(Math.cos(d_to_r(direction)))*step*factor;
scrollY = scrollY+(Math.sin(d_to_r(direction)))*step*factor;
```